# Looking for connector to repair xmas tree LED lights

Tags: power-supply, power, connector, repair

I have a string of LED christmas tree lights and the wires ripped off right at the strain relief of the connector that plugs into the power supply.

I was hoping to find a replacement connector with wires attached and connect the wires back to the LED light strand with a Wago connector. I can't seem to find this connector anywhere. Is this a standard connector I can purchase? Or am I SOL?

If there is a better way to approach this or if this is a dumb idea, feel free to let me know. Thank you!

[image: connector_view1]

[image: connector_view2]

[image: ripped wires]

[image: power supply]

Comment: You'll never find that.  It's custom to the maker of that set.   Cut the wire and splice if you can, otherwise throw it away (recycle....)

Comment: You can use some flush cutters or a hobby knife to carefully cut apart the connector and expose a few mm's of wire. There is probably 2cm more wire inside the rubber. Especially that "strain relief" section. Solder on to that and strain relive it better next time.

Comment: @KyleB I don't think that's true... I have several sets of a different brand and in a different country (Germany) which use the same connector.

Comment: Thanks to all for the comments!

Comment: One of Davide's links mentioned "Alitove". This seems to be [Alitove](https://www.alitove.net/) and also on Amazon [here](https://www.amazon.com/stores/ALITOVE/ALITOVE/page/50B7EB44-3444-496D-B856-0463878CFDF5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Drew says will work.
Drew commented

- You can use some flush cutters or a hobby knife to carefully cut apart the connector and expose a few mm's of wire. There is probably 2cm more wire inside the rubber. Especially that "strain relief" section. Solder on to that and strain relive it better next time.

In parallel with that, if you find some dressmaking pins which are solderable (plated brass ones usually are,  others may be - then pushing a pin into each conductor end for about half the available distance (5 to 10 mm?) then soldering with due enthusiasm may well work. This will work even better if you follow Drew's advice re trimming and then add the pins for support befoe soldering.

Once soldered, solder wires to the pins and trim to suit then insulate.
Sliding heatshrink onto each wire before soldering and then sliding it hard against the plug before shrinking should be able to be adequate as the output is 30V at <= 300 mA. Overlay the heatshrink with either larger heatshrink that goes over the plug body, or self amalgamating rubber tape, or good quality electrical tape.

In such repairs there is a small chance of shorting between the two wires where they exit the plug. Being aware of this throughout should allow you to avoid it happening. Have the end repair as non flexible as possible at the plug exit point to maximise mechanical robustness. The soldered pins will help this.

Answer (score 3):

That is a circular connector of multiple yet unknown Chinese parentage commonly used in LED lighting. I have been asked to identify it multiple times over the last couple of years. I can find it all-over eBay, Amazon, and AliExpress, but damn if I can find who actually makes it or a model number. Therefore, the best I can do is point you to sites that sell terminated cables:

https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256801419038389.html

https://www.ebay.com/itm/195476749011

[https://www.amazon.com/ALITOVE-Female-Connector-Waterproof-0-75mm%C2%B2/dp/B07Q7ZY4XK/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Q7ZY4XK)

Comment: @DanW & Davide - one of Davide's links mentioned "Alitove". This seems to be [Alitove](https://www.alitove.net/) and also on Amazon [here](https://www.amazon.com/stores/ALITOVE/ALITOVE/page/50B7EB44-3444-496D-B856-0463878CFDF5)

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for exactly for the same connectors, but unfortunately the links seem to be dead. I found some potential matches, but it's not clear to me if they're the same or not: https://www.amazon.com/YETOR-Waterproof-Connectors-Connector-Extension/dp/B07WDBLFDN and https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005003643358373.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem finding rep. set for led christmas tree lights. Solution was to buy an "Extension cable" and cut the end I didn't use. Then I mounted the wires to the broken led light.  I fixed 6 x 1000 led bulbs each, in this way.
[image]
Extension cable set approx 3dollar (29NOK)

enter image description here

[image]
[image]
[image]